# Integration of Chatbot with Website - Challenges with Running Flask Backend and React Frontend Together

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, file, chatbot

I recently integrated a chatbot into my website, which involves both Python and JavaScript code. Initially, I had built the chatbot in a separate file, but I decided to merge it with my website code in a new file. However, I encountered an issue while trying to implement the app.py code (Python) into App.js (JavaScript) for the website.

In App.js, I tried to import the chatbot code using the file path ./components/layout/chatbot-solicitors-website/chatbot-deployment/standalone-frontend/app with the following import statement:

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import appcss from "./App.module.css";

import AboutUs from "./pages/AboutUs";
import BookOnline from "./pages/BookOnline";
import Firm from "./pages/Firm";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import LogIn from "./pages/LogIn";
import Publications from "./pages/Publications";
import Navbar from "./components/layout/Navbar";
import Footer from "./components/layout/Footer";
import ContactUs from "./components/layout/ContactUs";
import ChatWithUsButton from "./components/layout/ChatWithUsButton";
import ChatBot from "./components/layout/chatbot-solicitors-website/chatbot-deployment/standalone-frontend/app";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className={appcss.pagecontainer}>
      <div className={appcss.contentwrap}>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/about-us" element={<AboutUs />} />
          <Route path="/book-online" element={<BookOnline />} />
          <Route path="/firm" element={<Firm />} />
          <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<LogIn />} />
          <Route path="/publications" element={<Publications />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
      <ChatBot />
      <ChatWithUsButton />
      <ContactUs />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

However, I realized that it is not possible to directly run app.py (Python) within app.js (JavaScript). The issue arises because I need app.js to be executed through app.py first in order for the chatbot to function properly.

Here is the code snippet for app.py in my chatbot code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

from chat import get_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.get("/")
def index_get():
    return render_template("base.html")

@app.post("/predict")                   
def predict():
   text = request.get_json().get("message")
   # TO-DO: check if text is valid
   response = get_response(text)
   message = {"answer": response}
   return jsonify(message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=5001)
```

and here is the app.js code for my chatbot for more context:

```
class Chatbox {
    constructor() {
        this.args = {
            openButton: document.querySelector('.chatbox__button'),
            chatBox: document.querySelector('.chatbox__support'),
            sendButton: document.querySelector('.send__button')
        }

        this.state = false;
        this.messages = [];
    }

    display() {
        const {openButton, chatBox, sendButton} = this.args;

        openButton.addEventListener('click', () => this.toggleState(chatBox))

        sendButton.addEventListener('click', () => this.onSendButton(chatBox))

        const node = chatBox.querySelector('input');
        node.addEventListener("keyup", ({key}) => {
            if (key === "Enter") {
                this.onSendButton(chatBox)
            }
        })
    }

    toggleState(chatbox) {
        this.state = !this.state;

        // show or hides the box
        if(this.state) {
            chatbox.classList.add('chatbox--active')
        } else {
            chatbox.classList.remove('chatbox--active')
        }
    }

    onSendButton(chatbox) {
        var textField = chatbox.querySelector('input');
        let text1 = textField.value
        if (text1 === "") {
            return;
        }

        let msg1 = { name: "User", message: text1 }
        this.messages.push(msg1);

        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ message: text1 }),
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
          })
          .then(r => r.json())
          .then(r => {
            let msg2 = { name: "Sam", message: r.answer };
            this.messages.push(msg2);
            this.updateChatText(chatbox)
            textField.value = ''

        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            this.updateChatText(chatbox)
            textField.value = ''
          });
    }

    updateChatText(chatbox) {
        var html = '';
        this.messages.slice().reverse().forEach(function(item, index) {
            if (item.name === "Sam")
            {
                html += '<div class="messages__item messages__item--visitor">' + item.message + '</div>'
            }
            else
            {
                html += '<div class="messages__item messages__item--operator">' + item.message + '</div>'
            }
          });

        const chatmessage = chatbox.querySelector('.chatbox__messages');
        chatmessage.innerHTML = html;
    }
}


const chatbox = new Chatbox();
chatbox.display();
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to seamlessly integrate my Flask backend (app.py) with my React frontend (App.js) to make the chatbot fully functional within my website. Specifically, I need to understand how to ensure that app.js runs through app.py first.

Thank you in advance for your help!